# Pass a variable from controller to view when using form_open

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am very new to codeigniter and I was wondering if someone can help me. I want to pass a variable from my controller to my view, but the way I am do it it always give a undefined variable error. Also, if I keep the load->view call give an error too!
So, how can I pass the variable to the view? Thanks in advance to any help!

```
<?php <!-- view -->
    echo form_open('match/setDefafultEmail', array(
        'class' => '',
    ));
?>
<div class="well">
<div class="text-center">
    <h4>Set Default Email</h4>
</div>
<?php 

echo("<div>");
echo form_label('Email:');
echo form_input(array(
                    'id' => 'email_address',
                    'name' => 'email_address',
                    'type' => 'email',
                    'placeholder' => 'email@example.com',
                    'value' => set_value('email_address'),
                    'required' => '',
                    'title' => 'Email address'
                    ));
echo("</div>");

echo("<div>");
echo form_submit(array(
    'id' => 'btn',
    'name' => 'min',
    'type' => 'Submit',
    'class' => 'btn btn-info',
    'value' => 'Set Default Email'
));
echo("</div>");
    echo form_close()
?>
<br>
<br>
<table class="table" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Default Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr class="info">
        <!--display current default name and email--> 
       <?php foreach($info as $row):?>
        <td> <?php echo $row->full_name ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $row->email ?> </td>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

public function setDefafultEmail(){

```
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Email Address', 'valid_email');

    if ($this->form_validation->run( ) == true){

        $name = $this->input->post('full_name');
        $default_email = $this->input->post('email_address');
        $this->spw_vm_request_model->setEmailToDefault($name,$default_email);
    }
    $data['info'] = $this->request_model->getDefaultEmailAndName();
    $this->load->view('admin/admin_dashboard',$data);
    redirect('admin/admin_dashboard');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) After you load the view you don't need to redirect. When you redirect('admin/admin_dashboard') you actually call the admin_dashboard Controller.
2) On your View you are trying to access an array as an object( **$row->full_name** ) I think you should use $row['full_name'].
3) In case your Model returns an object, you have to serialize it in your Controller and unserialize it in your View.